# SQL how to find who is missing an item

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a database with employees, employee items, departments and Department items.
Each employee in each department has to have specific Department items.

Example: Department Y have five different Department items a,b,c,d and each employee has to have those four item in the Employee items table. But the Department items may have 2 of a, 3 of b, 4 of c and 1 of d that the employee needs to have in the Employee Items table.

I have tried with different Sql's but I cannot get the right result.
Thanks for any help.

I have the following tables.

Employee table

```
EmpNum, Department, Gender
100      AAA          M
101      AAA          F
102      BBB          M
103      BBB          F
104      AAA          M
105      BBB          F
```

EmpProducts table

```
EmpNum,Item
100      A1
100      A1
100      A2
101      A2
102      B1
102      B3
103      B2
104      A1
104      A2
105      B1
```

Products

```
Deparment, Item, QtyM, QtyF
AAA         A1     2     1
AAA         A2     1     0
AAA         A3     1     1
BBB         B1     1     1
BBB         B2     2     3
BBB         B3     3     3
```

Each employee need to have a specific amount of product that is assigned to the employees department I need to know if they have to little or to many. the result should be.

100 have the correct items for the gender and department so he should not be in the result.

```
101  A2  1     She is 1 over the 0 she should have.
102  B2 -2
102  B3 -2
103  B1 -1
103  B2 -2
103  B2 -3
104  A1 -1
104  A3 -1
105  B2 -3
105  B3 -3
```

Comment: Could you show us 'different SQLs' that you have tried.

Comment: In addition show some example data and an example of the query result you expect. Also, provide the version of SQL Server which you are using.

Comment: In other words you need to find out the count of employee items of each type per employee, and compare that count to the required counts for their given department? Do you have a table that says 'employees in department Y must have 2 of a'?

Answer (score 1):

```
CREATE TABLE Departments (DepartmentId INT, DepartmentName VARCHAR(30))
CREATE TABLE DepartmentItems 
    (DepartmentItemId INT, DepartmentId INT, ItemName VARCHAR(30))
CREATE TABLE Employee
    (EmployeeId INT, DepartmentId INT, EmployeeName VARCHAR(100))
CREATE TABLE EmployeeItems (EmployeeId INT, DepartmentItemId INT)

INSERT Departments VALUES (1, 'Department A'), (2, 'Department B')
-- Depart A has three items
INSERT DepartmentItems VALUES
    (1, 1, 'Item A'), (2, 1, 'Item B'), (3, 1, 'Item C')
-- Department B has two items
INSERT DepartmentItems VALUES (4, 2, 'Item D'), (5, 2, 'Item E')

-- Two employees
INSERT Employee VALUES (1, 1, 'Kim'), (2, 2, 'Tom')

-- Kim's items
INSERT EmployeeItems VALUES (1, 1), (1, 2) -- Missing Item C from Department A..

-- Tom's items
INSERT EmployeeItems VALUES (2, 4) -- Missing Item E from Department B

-- Who is missing an item..
SELECT d.*, di.*, e.*
FROM Departments d
INNER JOIN DepartmentItems di
    ON di.[DepartmentId] = d.[DepartmentId]
INNER JOIN Employee e
    ON e.[DepartmentId] = d.[DepartmentId]
LEFT JOIN EmployeeItems ei
    ON ei.[EmployeeId] = e.[EmployeeId]
    AND ei.[DepartmentItemId] = di.[DepartmentItemId]
WHERE ei.[DepartmentItemId] IS NULL
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks Tom it was the INNER JOIN I didn't understand but you painted a good picture.

Comment: I got it almost working, but I have to know the count of theDepartmentIteId and see if it's below the amount they should have.

Comment: For example a Female (e.Gender) should have 3 of item C (ei.QtyF) but a Male should only have 2 item C (ei.QtyM). Usually I put COUNT in the select statement, but I don't see how to put it on ei.DepartmentItemsId